# Inclusion of plugins in maven pom file conditionally (without profiles)

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have got a scenario where I should include some special maven plugins w.r.t. jar signing in my root pom.XML file.

As soon as I include them, build fails for me as these jar signer maven plugins are part of only build server and are not locally.

For me, I am looking for a possibility to conditionally include these maven plugins -> based on supplying of a command line argument (similar to activation of profiles)
Note: I don't want to use profile for this usecase, as already in my pom there are too many profiles and if I use this concept then I will end up duplicating lot of code which is difficult for maintenance

Comment: First the solution in this case is a profile which will be automatically being triggers via a property on your build server (Jenkins?) furthermore if you have many profiles than there is already a smell in your build...what kind of profiles do you have and for what purposes?

Comment: we build our product for different targets (e.g: mars, neon, oxygen) and based on them there are some specific criteria for each profile. Yes our profiles are triggered based on the property on jenkins

Comment: So first we are talking about an OSGi build ?

Comment: To simply it we will not mixup osgi build stuff here.. the scenario which i am looking is a general one.. where in I am looking for conditional inclusion of plugins in a maven build